# Finding line is self intersected or not using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, linestring, self-intersection

**I have to find whether the line feature is self intersected or not.**

I have tried the below logic but I am not getting it.

Is there a way to find the solution?

```
    lineLayerName=self.lineLayer.name()
    for ft in self.lineLayer.getFeatures():
        if ft.geometry().intersects(ft.geometry()):
            gem = ft.geometry().intersection(ft.geometry())
            intPt=gem.asPoint()
            if intPt.x() != 0 and intPt.y() != 0:
                print "Self-intersected"
```

If the line is self-intersected means I need the intersected point. I have attached the screenshot for reference.

[image: Line Self-intersected]

Answer (score 6):

*QgsGeometry* has the *isSimple()* function that will return `False` for a line that self intersects.

```
lineLayerName=self.lineLayer.name()
for ft in self.lineLayer.getFeatures():
    if not ft.geometry().isSimple():
        print "Not simple - self-intersect"
```