# Crossing line unexpectedly returns False using crosses() in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, crossing

I have a LineString that I modify by extending the line. After extending it I want to check if it crosses itself. I am using [`QgsGeometry().crosses()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.crosses) to test this. For example:

```py
wkt_new = 'MultiLineString ((688017.94950945943128318 5331570.45111508388072252, 684852.62947463185992092 5328735.23067484982311726, 686420.68171600450295955 5329768.71965211816132069, 690305.1747684960719198 5330196.37026340141892433, 691766.31435704790055752 5330873.48373126704245806, 696755.57148868835065514 5329234.15638801362365484, 699285.83760544890537858 5327915.56700322311371565, 701352.81555998569820076 5329661.80699929688125849, 697483.55642176070250571 5328310.3356888284906745))'
wkt_old = 'MultiLineString ((684852.62947463185992092 5328735.23067484982311726, 686420.68171600450295955 5329768.71965211816132069, 690305.1747684960719198 5330196.37026340141892433, 691766.31435704790055752 5330873.48373126704245806, 696755.57148868835065514 5329234.15638801362365484, 699285.83760544890537858 5327915.56700322311371565, 701352.81555998569820076 5329661.80699929688125849))'

geom_new = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_new)
geom_old = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_old)

print(geom_new.crosses(geom_old))
```

unexpectedly returns **False**.

How could I check if a line crosses itself (or more general: another geometry/line)?

[image]

Comment: In crosses predicate between lines, the intersection between their interiors (all the line except start and end points) must return points (dim(II) = 0). Maybe you need to compare only the extension segments to know if they cross the original line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Finding line is self intersected or not using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353194/finding-line-is-self-intersected-or-not-using-pyqgis)

[isSimple()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.isSimple)

> Determines whether the geometry is simple (according to OGC
> definition), i.e. it has no anomalous geometric points, such as
> self-intersection or self-tangency. Uses GEOS library for the test.
>
> This is useful mainly for linestrings and linear rings. Polygons are
> simple by definition, for checking anomalies in polygon geometries one
> can use isGeosValid().

```
wkt_new = 'MultiLineString ((688017.94950945943128318 5331570.45111508388072252, 684852.62947463185992092 5328735.23067484982311726, 686420.68171600450295955 5329768.71965211816132069, 690305.1747684960719198 5330196.37026340141892433, 691766.31435704790055752 5330873.48373126704245806, 696755.57148868835065514 5329234.15638801362365484, 699285.83760544890537858 5327915.56700322311371565, 701352.81555998569820076 5329661.80699929688125849, 697483.55642176070250571 5328310.3356888284906745))'
wkt_old = 'MultiLineString ((684852.62947463185992092 5328735.23067484982311726, 686420.68171600450295955 5329768.71965211816132069, 690305.1747684960719198 5330196.37026340141892433, 691766.31435704790055752 5330873.48373126704245806, 696755.57148868835065514 5329234.15638801362365484, 699285.83760544890537858 5327915.56700322311371565, 701352.81555998569820076 5329661.80699929688125849))'

geom_new = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_new)
geom_old = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_old)

new_layer = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString?crs=epsg:31255", "New", "Memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)

feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geom_new)
new_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
new_layer.updateFields()

for ft in new_layer.getFeatures():
    if not ft.geometry().isSimple():
        print ("Not simple - self-intersect")
    else:
        print("Simple - no intersect")
```

Comment: So does crosses() always return false if one of the two geometries is not simple?

Comment: isSimple() just tests one geometry (self) according to https://www.ogc.org/standard/sfa/   --> Basic methods on geometric objects